# How to determine $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\downarrow0}\phi_{\epsilon}(x)$ if $\phi_{\epsilon}$ solves $u'=\frac{sin(\epsilon u)^2}{u+\epsilon}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $\epsilon\gt{0}$, $\phi_{\epsilon}\text{ solves ODE }$
$$\begin{cases}
u'=\frac{sin(\epsilon u)^2}{u+\epsilon}\\[2ex]
u(0)=1
\end{cases}$$
**Problem**:Determine $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\downarrow0}\phi_{\epsilon}(x)$ for arbitrary $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

How can we determine it without actually solving $u$ of this initial problem.
I have tried to solve this equation by separable equation, but i didn't solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For $ϵ=0$ you get $u'=0$ and thus $u(x)=1$ as hypothesis for the limit. The only possible singularity is at or close to roots of $u$, but these should only occur at $|x|\sim 1/ϵ$, thus not an obstacle for the limit process.

Comment: sorry, i still didn't get it. and why $u'=0\implies u(x)=1$.

Comment: Because $u(0)=1$. For bounded values, say as long as $1/10<u(x)<10$, the right side expands as $u'=\frac12(\frac12ϵ^2(2u)^2-\frac1{24}ϵ^4(2u)^4+...)u^{-1}(1-ϵu^{-1}+ϵ^2u^{-2}+...)$ $=ϵ^2u-ϵ^3-ϵ^4\frac13u^3+ϵ^4u^{-1}+...$ So you get in the first approximation $u(x)=e^{ϵ^2x}$, and as long as $ϵ^2|x|\ll1$, this stays close to $u(x)=1$. The higher order corrections will not change that.